# Create image with PHP and store it in a server folder

Tags: php, imagejpeg

**Solved The Problem!!!**

1. As Moni said I need to pass 3 parameters to the `imagejpeg` but small correction it shouldn't be `imagejpeg($im,$save,0)` it supposed to be `imagejpeg($im,$save,100)` image quality has to be **100** in order to get the quality pictures
2. Image folder is without the slashes "images/fb/"
3. Also for the `imagecolorallocate` `imagecolorallocate($im, 142, 011, 029)` three digit RGB to get the proper output.

So, the answer for this and the full code is given below

```
<?php
// Create image with 2 line of text
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(600, 300);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 142, 011, 029);
imagestring($im, 10, 5, 5,  'Some Text String', $text_color);
imagestring($im, 10, 5, 50,  'Some Text String 2', $text_color);

// Set the content type header as image/jpeg
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Output the image
//imagejpeg($im);    //up-to this point its working well 

$name="test2";
$save = "images/fb/". strtolower($name) .".jpeg";
imagejpeg($im, $save, 100);   //Saves the image
imagejpeg($im);              //Displays the image

// Free up memory
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

**Problem**

Please Help me to solve this problem that I have,

I am trying to create an image by php and trying to store the created image inside a folder, image did displayed but when I add the saving into folder it is giving me error. following is the code I tried.

```
<?php
// Create image with 2 line of text
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(600, 300);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 142, 11, 29);
imagestring($im, 10, 5, 5,  'Some Text String', $text_color);
imagestring($im, 10, 5, 50,  'Some Text String 2', $text_color);

// Set the content type header as image/jpeg
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Output the image
//imagejpeg($im);    //up-to this point its working well 

$name="test";
$save = "/images/fb/". strtolower($name) .".jpeg";

imagejpeg($im, $save, 0, NULL);

// Free up memory
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

following is the error I am getting

```
The image "path" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.
```

my folder structure is

```
->www
  -> projectFolder 
   -> subFolder
      ->phpFile
      ->imageFolder (images)
        ->imageSubFolder (fb)
```

I have tried with `chmod` as well but its seems permission is not the problem because I am trying this in Localhost.

Any advice would be appreciated...

Comment: Are you sure that path `/images/fb/` exists? `/` means this is main folder on server, not your local `images/fb/` folder

Comment: Perhaps your path is wrong? What's the error?

Comment: _"...it is giving me error"_ ... and the error is?

Comment: `$save = "/path/to/www/images/fb/". strtolower($name) .".jpeg";` You need to either use the full server path, or use a relative path and omit the slash before images `$save = "images/fb/". strtolower($name) .".jpeg";`

Comment: I did tried with the relative path by omitting the / in-front of images, that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You create the image as `$im` and then try to save it as `.$my_img`

Change this: `imagejpeg($my_img, $save, 0);`

To: `imagejpeg($im, $save, 0);`

Comment: Yes, that's a mistake, "Corrected" though still same issue :(

Comment: And just to clarify, **Null** also can be used as a parameter for `imagejpeg` according to the PHP manual.. if I am not setting any quality for the image.

Comment: imagejpeg has only 3 parameters. You can use NULL for the $to parameter if you want to set the quality and do not want to provide the $to parameter: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

Comment: Thank you moni_dragu, there are few thinks needs to be changed along with your suggestion. Thank you for directing me!